# Twilio SendGrid Global Email Statistics Access Forbidden

Tags: sendgrid, twilio-api

I have setup a SendGrid API key with full access and was trying to get global email statistics using the online tool that goes with the documentation ... but the response I get says access forbidden. I'm not sure what to do because my API key has full access. Can anyone with experience using the Twilio SendGrid API offer advice?

[image: Access Forbidden using the API]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I think the issue here is that you have the default `on-behalf-of` text still in the form. It's not a regular placeholder text, but actual text.

Delete the text that start "The subuser's username..." and try again. It should work.